# How to find the position of inner tag and focus it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to select the inner tag. Suppose i want to select the last inner tag of `<series>` and need to focus() it. Could you please any one help on this?

```
<series>
      <point></point>
      <point></point>
      <point></point>
      <point></point>
      <point></point>
      <point></point>
      <point></point>
    </series
```

Thanks,

Bharathi.

Answer (score 1):

The last one? Easy!

```
$('series').children('point').last().focus();
```

The children function returns a jquery object with all the 'point' elements it could find directly below series.

You can also traverse these in a loop using the .next() and .previous() functions.

EDIT: Then there's two ways you can select it:

```
$($('series').children('point')[4]).focus();
```

This will select the fifth child.

Alternatively use a find if the element has something unique about it

```
$('series').children('point').find('uniqueIdentifier').focus();
```

Comment: " Suppose i want to select the last inner tag of <series> and need to focus() it " , not " that is the only tag I want to focus "

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last` to get the desired last elem in a specified context like below:

```
$('series').find('point:last').focus();
```

or any last inner child:

```
$('series').children(':last').focus();
```

Comment: " Suppose i want to select the last inner tag of <series> and need to focus() it " , not " that is the only tag I want to focus "

Comment: @harsha see the second one may be this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `last()`:

```
$( 'point' ).last().focus();
```

Comment: " Suppose i want to select the last inner tag of <series> and need to focus() it " , not " that is the only tag I want to focus "